# MEAN stack facebook login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, facebook, passport.js

I am trying to deploy an application that uses passport facebook strategy. I've been testing my app on localhost first and then tried to deploy it to AWS.

Everything seemed working fine on my local machine, but when i deployed i tried logging in with multiple facebook accounts.

I saved the received variables in an api call and retrieved those via angular

However, my first authenticated user, everything seems working fine, but when the second user authenticates it will override his variables like username, profile image etc.

I know why it is doing this. But i don't immediatly have a solution in mind.

Here is my server side code when i authenticate

```
app.get('/login/facebook',
  passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('/login/facebook/return', 
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
    UserID = req.user.id;
    UserDisplayName = req.user.displayName;

    UserProfileImage = req.user._json.picture.data.url;
    console.log(req.user._json.picture.data.url)

    var User = UserID + UserDisplayName;
    var ProfilePicture = UserProfileImage
    res.json({name: User , url: ProfilePicture});
  });

app.get('/profileInfo', function(req, res){
    var User = UserID + UserDisplayName;
    var ProfilePicture = UserProfileImage
    res.json({name: User , url: ProfilePicture});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you store your users?

From your code i quess that you save your user's id in UserID variable but when next user logs in it will get overwritten.

I'm only quessing since i can't see your whole code but try something like this:

```
var users = {};

app.get('/login/facebook/return',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {

    // save user to users object
    users[req.user.id] = {
      displayName: req.user.displayName,
      profileImage: req.user._json.picture.data.url
    }

    res.redirect('/');
  });

// you need to use some kind of sessions or cookies to know which user this is
// for simplicity let's assume you get profile by user's id /profileInfo/:id
app.get('/profileInfo/:id', function(req, res) {

  res.json(users[req.params.id]);

});
```